# PHP: Excluding URL Path from URL Rewrite Rules

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have the following rewrite rule in wordpress:

`add_rewrite_rule('members/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=members&username=$matches[1]','top');`

This rewrites everything after www.mysite.com/members/ in the URL address.

My challenge is to keep that functionality but exclude the following URL path: www.mysite.com/members/info/.

Can anybody please help me do so?

Comment: you can just add a new rule after, and define any behavior you need. And it will overwrite previous for this particular case

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. The problem is I am still having difficulty with Regular Expressions, I am watching a few youtube tutorials as we speak but if you can point me in the right direction at least as to how to go about writing that rule, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I figured it out, for anyone interested this will most likely work: add_rewrite_rule('members/(?!info)(.+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=members&username=$matches[1]','top');

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to .htaccess before other directives.

```
RewriteRule members/ - [L]
```