# .htaccess change for shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I have shared hosting from Godaddy with the basic  (/.) as my opencart shop site

now i have made a folder domains in shared hosting and made other websites in it
e.g.
/domains/otherwebsitefolder/

when i allow access in .htaccess for main directory that is basic (/....) then the .htaccess is applied to sub-folder domains to and thus other site are disturbed....
How to change .htaccess so that it does not effect subdomains folder!

I use opencart 5.3.2 with htaccess as follows

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200
```

Comment: I take it you are on _PHP_ 5.3.2 - OpenCart is only 1.5.5.1 at present. Do you mean the issue is that you are getting rewrites happening on the subfolder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to exclude a folder for rewriting rules just use this

```
RewriteRule members/ - [L]
```

as i explained at [PHP: Excluding URL Path from URL Rewrite Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595160/php-excluding-url-path-from-url-rewrite-rules/13595599#13595599)

also you may need to change basedir  as

```
RewriteBase /foldername/
```